# record a split screen remote help session with windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, recording

Iam having a lesson shown to me remotely and want to record it so I can go back and look at it again if I need to. Is there a way to make a recording of it with sound too?
Thank,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

You just record your screen with a screen recorder, like [this free one](https://icecreamapps.com/Screen-Recorder/). Just google `Free Screen Recorder`. *Not sponsoring Icecream Screen Recorder just one that I use, that is free*